# Unable to connect to MS SQL Server using pyodbc on Scintific Linux 7.5

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7

My `OS` is `Scientific Linux 7.5` and wants to connect to `MS SQL server` using `python 2.7.5` i have configured `unixODBC 2.3.1` and  `Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server`

But when i use the following code:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
'Driver={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2};'
'Server=localhost;'
'User=sa;'
'Password=xxx;'
'Database=yyy;'
'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

i get the following error

```
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', u'[HY000] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000) (851968) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

and got the same error when used `'Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'`

if i use '`Driver={SQL Server};'` i got stuck on following error

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', u"[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Comment: Authentication type is SQL Server

Comment: If you're provided a username and password, then the connection isn't a trusted connection, it's using SQL Authentication. Also, you really shouldn't be using the `sa` account for your application; it should have it's own login/user and only have permission to do the things it needs to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove `'Trusted_Connection=yes;'` from your connection string. It is used for Windows authentication, while you are trying to connect with SQL authentication (providing user name and password).

Comment: Hi Andrey,I am trying to make connection for windows authenticated account and getting error-> ```pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: Credential cache is empty (851968) (SQLDriverConnect)').```
Can you please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate cause and solution, in case anyone ends up here for this reason:

If you're relying on an `env` file to populate the Username and Password components of the pyodbc connection string, and something goes wrong with your execution such that those values are not accessible, then you will get that `No Kerberos credentials available` error message.

Check the value of the connection string; in my case, the username and password were missing from the SQLAlchemy engine string when I printed it.  Running my docker container with the proper `--env-file=` flag addressed this case.